# Facebook Graph - getting my pictures

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for the fastest way to get all the pictures I'm tagged in with someone specific.

As for now I need to check "my photos" then "the other someone's photos" and then photos in albums of all my friends.

it takes forever.

I need a way (I guess it's an FQL request) to get **all** the photos me and a specific friend are tagged in together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting **some** of the photos easy to do with an FQL Query:

```
SELECT object_id, src, owner, caption, created 
     FROM photo 
     WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me())
       AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = 'MY_FRIENDS_ID')
```

(In this example `MY_FRIENDS_ID` could also be an event id or a group id)

Facebook has limits on the number of objects returned by an FQL query. To get all of the items, you'll have to write a script that appends `AND created < {OLDEST_DATE_RETURNED_BY_LAST_QUERY}` to your FQL and repeats the query until no data is returned.

Demo query here of photos you are tagged in: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20object_id%2C%20src%2C%20owner%2C%20caption%2C%20created%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20object_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20photo_tag%20WHERE%20subject%20%3D%20me())

Comment: this is returning the smallest size imgs. is it possible to get the original or larger size. thanks

Comment: There are lots of other sizes available. Take a look at the [photo table FQL Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/)

Comment: It's a good answer,  but it doesn't answer what I needed. I edited the question so it will be clearer.